# How to automaticaly assign textures based on their name to a Dictionary<T,Texture>

Tags: unity, assets, file

I have a state machine that the controls the flows and transitions of the states, the thing is that I have a script that requires textures to transition to in-between scripts, what I want to do is to make a class which searches a folder and assigns the specific texture to a specific class and stores it into `Dictionary<T,Texture>`.

Code for the state machine:

```
public class StationBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, IStationStateSwitcher
{
    private CrossFade _fader;
    private Dictionary<Type, Texture> _stateTextures;

    private BaseState _currentState;
    private List<BaseState> _allStates;
    private void Start()
    {
        _fader = GetComponent<CrossFade>();
        _allStates = new List<BaseState>()
        {
            new IdleState(_fader, _stateTextures[typeof(IdleState)],this),
            new EatState(_fader, _stateTextures[typeof(EatState)],this),
            new WorkState(_fader, _stateTextures[typeof(WorkState)],this),
            new SleepState(_fader, _stateTextures[typeof(SleepState)],this),
        };
        _currentState = _allStates[0];
    }
    public void SwitchState<T>() where T : BaseState
    {
        var state = _allStates.FirstOrDefault(s => s is T);
        _currentState.Exit();
        state.Enter();
        _currentState = state;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the rule you want to use "based on their name"?

Comment: Like their type, as in IdleState, WorkState, etc.